# Jmeter save results as Html

Tags: java, jmeter

I am using jmeter for functional testing and want to store the result from the view result tree listener to a file in html format.

Is that somehow possible? Actual I just can save the result as xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "tell" JMeter to save response body into .jtl results file the following way:

1. For one time execution it could be done via -J command line arguments:

   ```
   jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true -n -t ...
   ```
2. For "permanent" changes add below lines to *user.properties* file (it sits under JMeter's bin folder)

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
   jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
   ```

Be aware that in case of heavy load test it will result in massive disk IO on JMeter size so it's recommended to store response data for test development and/or debugging purposes only.

If you're not interested in default metrics like timestamp, label, response code, elapsed, etc. - you can turn them off taking this "properties" approach.

References:

- [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
- [JMeter Performance and Tuning Tips](https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I got a xml file now, but how can I turn this to html? Is there an xls for transforming? Or do I have to write my own?

Comment: There are. Take a look at `extras` folder in your JMeter installation, there should be 5 xsl files, personally I would go for `jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl` one

Answer (score 4):

If you want to convert .jtl files, try this. (Just watch out that .jtl is regular CSV file, no columns missing):

```
jmeter -g [absolute_path_to_jtl_file] -o [path_to_some_empty_folder]
```

It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the listener [Save Responses to a file](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) and store the response of the requests in a file.

Comment: The only problem here is, that there is a file for every response, I just want one single file for the responses

Answer (score 0):

SmartMeter (free JMeter extension) is capable of doing HTML reports, even from existing JTL files. Read more in this [article](https://www.smartmeter.io/blog/smartmeter-load-test-report).